# Entity Framework not saving jsonb property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an update method:

```
    public class User
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    }

     public async Task<bool> Update(int id, UserRequest user)
     {

      var result = await _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

      var cities = new List<string>();
      cities.Add("New York");
      cities.Add("London");

            result = new Users()
            {
               Id = result.Id,
               FirstName = user.FirstName,
               LastName = user.LastName,
               City = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cities)
            };

         //  _context.Entry(result).Property(x => x.City).IsModified = true;

         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         return true;
      }
```

FirstName and LastName change is reflected in db but not in City db.

```
  _context.Entry(result).Property(x => x.City).IsModified = true;
```

As a solution, generally used the Entry feature, but the `Entry` property throws an error for me:

> An exception occurred while calculating the database error page content.
> Skipping display of the database error page.
> System.InvalidOperationException:
> StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.

Comment: Where is your update? Question is too simplified. Even with errors.

Comment: Shouldnt your attribute appear above the property? Not below it?

Comment: For update, just change `result` properties, assigning new object to local variable, do nothing; `result.City = ...`

Comment: @mxmissile i fixed it but i still get the error.

Comment: Show your updated code please.

Comment: I solved the issue, I don't understand why it is like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the cause of the issue but the following change solved my issue.

```
    result = new Users()
    {
       Id = result.Id,
       FirstName = user.FirstName,
       LastName = user.LastName,
       City = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cities)
    };
```

#### to

```
      result.FirstName = user.FirstName;
      result.LastName = user.LastName ;
      result.City = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cities);
```